# I don't understand why is this for loop so fast?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, permutation

Today I was solving Project Euler's problem #43
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZENN.png) and I ran into a somewhat interesting problem. I don't understand why is my code so fast?

```
from itertools import permutations
def main():
    numbers1_9 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    list_of_all_permutations = list(permutations(numbers1_9, 10))
    length_of_my_list = len(list_of_all_permutations)
    number_of_times_it_ran=0
    result = []
    for n in list_of_all_permutations:
        number_of_times_it_ran+=1
        if n[0] == 0:
            continue
        elif n[3] % 2 == 0 and (n[2]+n[3]+n[4]) % 3 == 0 and n[5] % 5 ==0 and int(str(n[4])+str(n[5])+str(n[6])) % 7 == 0 and (n[5]+n[7]-n[6]) % 11 == 0 and int(str(n[6])+str(n[7])+str(n[8])) % 13 == 0 and int(str(n[7])+str(n[8])+str(n[9])) % 17 == 0:
            temp_list = []
            for digits_of_n in n:
                temp_list.append(str(digits_of_n))
            result.append(int("".join(temp_list)))
            print(f"Added {temp_list}, Remaining: {length_of_my_list-number_of_times_it_ran}")
    print(f"The code ran {number_of_times_it_ran} times and the result is {sum(result)}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I mean it went through the for loop 3,628,800 times, checked all those parameters, and only took a second.

```
Added ['1', '4', '0', '6', '3', '5', '7', '2', '8', '9'], Remaining: 3142649
Added ['1', '4', '3', '0', '9', '5', '2', '8', '6', '7'], Remaining: 3134251
Added ['1', '4', '6', '0', '3', '5', '7', '2', '8', '9'], Remaining: 3124649
Added ['4', '1', '0', '6', '3', '5', '7', '2', '8', '9'], Remaining: 2134649
Added ['4', '1', '3', '0', '9', '5', '2', '8', '6', '7'], Remaining: 2126251
Added ['4', '1', '6', '0', '3', '5', '7', '2', '8', '9'], Remaining: 2116649
The code ran 3628800 times, and the result is 16695334890
```

This is the output. The code finished in 1.3403266999521293 seconds.

Comment: Do you have a concrete, objective reason why you'd expect anything different?

Comment: @charles-duffy Well, I am happy that it ran as fast as it did, but I wondered why is this for loop so quick, even though it has so many parameters. The reason I am asking is so that I can implement it in my other code.

Comment: Your processor runs multiple billions of times per second. You're not doing anything really computationally costly in this function just a few comparisons and arithmetic. Consider also that  successive `and` statements in Python are short-circuiting, so the `if` fails as soon as any of the `and` statements fail and the rest of the `if` statement isn't executed.

Comment: Processor speeds are measured in GHz (billions of operations per second).  Doing a few million iterations of a loop in about a second is easy as long as the average iteration is on the order of a thousand instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It runs so quickly because of the short-circuiting feature of logical operators. The first three conditions in the `if` statement are easy to calculate, and they filter out the vast majority (around 97%) of all the permutations, so you hardly ever need to execute the more expensive operations like `int(str(n[4])+str(n[5])+str(n[6]))`.

So when you have a bunch of conditions that you're connecting with `and`, and the order that they're tested doesn't matter for the logic, you should put the ones that are easiest to test or are most likely to fail first.